# highlight factor with highest value in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Lets simulate some data:

```
library(stringi)
set.seed(12)

value<-round(rnorm(25,5,5))
group<-rep(LETTERS[1:5],5)
special<-stri_rand_strings(25, 5, pattern = "[A-Z,]")
abc<-cbind.data.frame(group, value,special)
```

and then plot it

```
ggplot(abc)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=group, y=value))+
  geom_point(aes(x=group, y=value, color=special))
```

[image]

I would like to have labels for the "special" column where "special" has max "value" per group displayed next to the points for each "group", as drawn on the image.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach adds a text geom to the max value per group, and `label` is the `special` variable

```r
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(12)

value<-round(rnorm(25,5,5))
group<-rep(LETTERS[1:5],5)
special<-stri_rand_strings(25, 5, pattern = "[A-Z,]")
abc<-cbind.data.frame(group, value,special)
glimpse(abc)
#> Rows: 25
#> Columns: 3
#> $ group   <chr> "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C…
#> $ value   <dbl> -2, 13, 0, 0, -5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 7, 1, -1, 1, 5, 4, 1, 11, 7, 8, …
#> $ special <chr> "JIKHN", "ZOOQV", "TKZOG", "DCTIT", "HSPJH", "YURDV", "NWCFS",…

ggplot(abc)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=group, y=value))+
  geom_point(aes(x=group, y=value, color=special)) +
  geom_text(data = abc %>% filter(value == max(value), .by = group),
            aes(label = special,
                x = group,
                y = value),
            nudge_y = 0.5
            ) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to filter your data for the max value per group. This filtered dataset can then be used in `geom_text`. For the "filtering" you could e.g. use `dplyr::slice_max`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(abc) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = group, y = value)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = group, y = value, color = special)) +
  geom_text(
    data = dplyr::slice_max(abc, value, n = 1, by = group),
    aes(x = group, y = value, label = special), vjust = 0, nudge_y = .25
  )
```

[image]